# Setting up mongo replication in production

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask, pymongo

How do you setup mongodb replication in production environments? I started using cloud formation with [this template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/step2b.html) but it crashes half way. I want to setup mongo so that it has one primary and two replications.

I haven't found a good tutorial for how to setup Mongo replication.

Some other questions I have are:

1. How does the failover work, if I have three Ec2 instances each with mongo and the primary fails. Another instance becomes the primary but how does my client PyMongo and Scala Mongo know the IP address of the new primary.
2. Lets say the primary goes down for 1 hour and there are 2,000 writes. When it goes back up, how does the primary gets updated. Do I need a script for this?

I am trying to do this with flask PyMongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up testing this on my local machine here is what I found.

1. Failover is done by the client, in the [Mongo URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#Connections-StandardConnectionStringFormat) you specify all your replications and when PyMongo connects to it. He checks to see which one is the primary and writes to that one.
2. When the database goes back up they all sync to match the same records in the all the databases.

Answer (score 0):

Readthedocs has step by step manual on setting up MongoDB cluster on different platforms, including AWS EC2:
https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2.html#deploy-a-multi-node-replica-set

To provide your clients with working mongo instance you can employ several different strategies. For example:

1. Set up Route53 failover. Route53 will monitor health instance of primary node, and change DNS record to point to secondary in case of failure.
2. Use service discovery. Consul, etc, ZooKeeper and doozerd are worth exploring.

In case of failing and then coming back a mongodb node will receive latest data from other nodes — that's just what replica set does.